# How can i detect that something is plugged in to the audio jack on linux with python?

Tags: python, linux, audio, tornado

I am using the python tornado webserver with tornado.io.

I want to prove that i can send events asynchronously via tornado.io.

How can i simply detect that something is plugged in the audio jack and send a message in tornado.io?

Comment: If you just want to test out sending events asynchronously it would be much easier to check whether a file exists with os.path.exists().  Just create or remove the file to test it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to find what is your sound card, then google for 'jack sensing for your audio_card_number" after that it is simple

```
import os
os.system("your_comand")
```

To get you started, here is a [python script](http://fijam.eu.org/other/headd/headd) which does for the ac97 card. Your solution should be similar.